# What does SO use to find “Questions that may already have your answer”?

Tags: support, search

Does it use a full-text searching engine like Lucene or does it use other data mining tools? I have a some xml data residing in a native xml database and am looking for ways to present to the user that this question (or parts of it) may have already been answered in a different question.

Comment: related (dupe?) [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/165773) (as of now, there's nothing about search there though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) - we used to use Lucene.NET.

Comment: Why isn't stackexchange featured? http://www.elasticsearch.org/users/

Comment: @JasjeevSingh - Ask them... We have just started using it - this is a fairly new development.

Comment: `<pedantic>`ElasticSearch *also* [uses](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/tree/master/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene) Lucene.`</pedantic>`