# Possible duplicate of [Please fix the code so the search terms actually find the duplicate]

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Seems to me the biggest cause of duplicates is that the search engine does not do an accurate match on what is a duplicate.

Now I know it's hard, but sometimes it's a little difficult for the questions asked to match the right search terms that are going to match something that already exists.

So is there any work that needs help in improving this?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what exactly you are trying to discuss.  Are you asking about trying to improve the search engine to make it easier to find duplicates?

Comment: If this is with regards to your previous posts, a simple search would have revealed plenty: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=comment+downvote So could you please clarify what is lacking and what specifically needs to be improved?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm confused as well. Because it seem to be **too hard** to find the question that I am duplicating. Or am I duplicating the response? Yes it seems the search engine fails in this regard. But let's just let everyone down-vote this rather than propose a forum to fix it.

Comment: @Bart if you want a real answer then perhaps suggest where is there somewhere to look? I have flagged duplictes. I've been flagged for duplicates. But I always search which others will not, and I always look at suggested, which others will not. But the answers don't match.  To really fix this is **off-topic** but I can possibly help here. If anyone is listening that is.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Nothing personal about you but it's quite simple, the search engine is inadequate, otherwise there would not need to be so may **possible duplicate** responses. So if someone on the dev team is watching, then that part needs help. I'm offering to help because it clearly needs it.

Comment: @NeilLunn if that's your point, then make it clearer.  Your question is extremely vague and really doesn't explain what exactly you think is wrong.

Comment: There are related questions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/dont-exclude-results-that-have-punctuation-just-because-the-query-doesnt) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204475/whats-wrong-with-my-search-terms). The search engine uses [Elastic Search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167282/158100).

Comment: You might want to dial the aggression/sarcasm down a bit, people are much more responsive to a neutral approach

Comment: @Clive Generally agree and I will. But unfortunately I have not been greeted in the same way. I wish it were different.

Comment: @Neil I'm sorry you feel that way (genuinely), I don't think people were trying to make you feel unwelcome, but I get that it can come across that way sometimes. However, you may well have a valid point here and it would be a shame for focus to be lost from that. If others ask for clarification, I always find the best assumption is that they've done it in good faith, and just want to properly understand what you're getting at

Comment: @Clive which is a good reason I would rather ditch the whole question. Look at the comments. I also had two useless responses. 90% is not asking for clarification but just an opinion. Kind of off topic but look at my SO profile page. I've been active for one month and that is my rep for the period. Pisses me to no end that I am just being talked down to here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I retracted my answer simply because you left the impression that the answer did not address your question exactly as Bart suggested.  If it does address your question, I'll be happy to undelete.  despite that fact that you seem positive I downvoted, I haven't simply because I still aren't sure what you are trying to get at.  Yes the search engine as limitations, but what are you trying to discuss?  How to fix?  Does it need fix?  Where does this relate to "possible duplicates".  I simply am trying to understand what your question is.

Comment: I don't get why you're so upset @NeilLunn. We're trying to clarify this question so we can discuss something. We're spending time on our Sunday to help you out here. I could have voted to close as "Unclear" and moved on, but none of us did. So help us help you out. And if that is too frustrating for you, just take a break.

Comment: @Bart I'm Calm. Please state exactly what you want clarified and I will try to do so. But this is more or a site dev focused question than anything else, so I'm glad for your understanding on that.

Comment: As a dev I can't do anything with this question - please clarify what you think is not working. You can do this by explaining what is currently happening that should not and what you believe should be happening - the more detailed the examples, the better. As it stands, this is not actionable.

Comment: Things like how you define a duplicate would help. If nothing else, it would help with focusing the discussion.

Comment: Once again I have no clue what that last sentence is supposed to mean, but let's give this a go: All I get from you post is "Search is not all that good to find duplicates", right? So then what? What did you experience? Where does it fall short? What does need to be adjusted? How do you propose it gets adjusted? If you don't have a proposal, what information are you looking for? Right now, to me at least, it is not so much a question as it is a statement.

Comment: @Oded can we establish some content off-site. This discussion here is not productive.

Comment: You can always email the community team via the [contact us form](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). We do, however, prefer having discussions in the open, here on Meta.

Comment: @Oded possible lag, but no match http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fix+the+search+terms as an example

Comment: Can you clarify? What is returned that you don't expect? What is not being returned that you do?

Comment: You say "fix", but don't explain the breakage - not everyone can see what you see, you know?

Comment: @Oded That is just a quickdraw, but it's pretty common. Something is up with how terms are tokenized for sure.

Comment: All I can see from you right now is "this is broken and needs to be fixed", without a "this" being properly defined. Do you understand?

Comment: @Oded How about this question? all the terms match do they not?

Comment: You mean that this very question does not show up within the search results? Because it does: http://i.imgur.com/XeB0c6p.png

Comment: That link to search you posted returned this question within the minute. It was the third result at least.

Comment: @Oded And maybe something in setting up the search tokens needs fixing. Which is my question. (scroll to top) The terms commonly do not match things that exist.

Comment: I shall reiterate. "something in setting up the search tokens needs fixing" is fuzzy and vague. It is not actionable. You claim this question doesn't return in search results when it plainly does. You wish the community and the team to take you seriously but will not clarify when requested?

Comment: @Bart So why is the question without **all** the terms on top?

Comment: @Oded Let's just be clear that you don't want to listen and leave it at that then.

Comment: Ah, so now we're getting somewhere. You're saying, if I search for specific terms, questions with titles containing all those terms should be sorted on top?

Comment: That could be applied to your exact attitude. As for the first result - it contains **all** of the terms, one of which is **also** a tag on the question.

Comment: Also take in account question votes, but it's hard to find duplicates when users are vague in what they're asking, or use words you have to know synonyms for.

Comment: @random Um yeah, thanks. That was really helpful

Comment: Look guys. I tried but this really isn't working. Too critical and not willing to listen. So this is over.

Comment: You came here. The community and team have requested you do clarify the issue, which you have refused to do. That's when it was over.

Comment: I tried I'm done. I was happy to help. Nobody listened. I won't bother again.

Comment: If you are happy to help, why not give a full description of the problem as you see it? Why insist on keeping things vague?

Comment: The search results are weighted on title, tags, votes and body content

Comment: @random really, I'm done on this but why order my relevance then? Does not make sense. No More. You just don't want to listen. Your all right.

Comment: If not by relevance, order how? How exactly is the ordering broken that you think should be fixed?

Comment: @Oded my last response. Look at all the **buddy** weighting on the comments here. I'm not part of your boys club. You don't want to listen. Why engage? You clearly don't want my opinion or knowledge. This is a useless exercise. If you think otherwise then I would not be seeing what I have seen.

Comment: So if any of you could do better to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115296/finding-two-documents-in-mongodb-that-share-a-key-value then feel free to keep talking down to me here.

Comment: **We** don't want to listen? We have asked for **more information** from you repeatedly. We are still waiting for that, instead of comments about "buddy weighting" and a general aggressive tone.

Comment: There is much work that needs help in improving this question.

Comment: Neil, *a note about clarifications:* when prompted for more info in Comments, we should **[edit] the Question to add more information** and clarify what's being requested. This way, other users, moderators or staff members *don't need* to read the whole comment thread to understand the issue. Anyway, the post ended up on hold exactly for this reason.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't understand your hostility.  Maybe its because you're getting downvoted..  but I believe that to only be because your question is unclear; why are you so against updating it to be clear?

Answer (score 3):

For me, the search engine of SO and the 'ask a question' form do a very good job of finding questions and answers that I wanted to find. The majority of the questions that are marked as duplicates are asked by people that do not look for questions that might answer their question. In some cases even googling the exact title of a question will yield pages of useful information. In the very few cases where searching didn't yield any useful posts, the search terms just don't appear in the questions or answers. No search engine improvement can find something that isn't there.

TL;DR The people that ask duplicate questions are usually the problem, not the search engine itself.

Comment: On the general point of "people do not search for the answers to their questions (first)" I'll agree with you. But I have been in this industry for over (hate to admit it), but 25 years now. And the SO (SO sites) do **not** match a natural language search. Otherwise I would not post this.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Well done. You just duplicated my number one repsone to people who don't search. What do you think that someone who actually understands search engine semantics did first?